# How can i do constrain in two direction? oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I need to do constraint witch dont let to insert this two row:

```
INSERT INTO table1
VALUES('LON','BUD',2000, SYSDATE);
INSERT INTO table1
VALUES('BUD','LON',2000, SYSDATE);
```

either

```
INSERT INTO table1
VALUES('LON','BUD',2000, SYSDATE);
```

so in my view LON , BUD is equal to BUD, LON

And if i need to insert for example: LON - BUD, BUD-LON, BUD-MAD... from an other table how can i check it before inserting it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a constraint - IMO you're better off doing this with a trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a function-based index:

```
create unique index table1_col1_col2 on table1(least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2));
```

Alternatively, you could add a constraint that `col1 < col2` and create a unique index on `col1, col2`.  You could enhance this by adding an insert/update trigger to swap the values when given in the "wrong" order.

Comment: +1. a check constraint is a very good solution in this case ( Triggers are never the right answer ).